# Can i call startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges, startMonitoringVisits and startMonitoringForRegion on the same CLLocationmanager?

Tags: ios, core-location

Is it ok to call on the **same CLLocationManager** `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, `startMonitoringVisits` and `startMonitoringForRegion` ? eventually also `startUpdatingLocation` ?

Comment: Yes. You can do that. No problem in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that should be fine. What makes you think you can't?

Comment: i don't know i just ask to be sure :) do you know if their is a way to know if the event DidUpdateLocations was fired because of startUpdatingLocation (so GPS accuracy) or startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges ?

Comment: I don't know of a way to distinguish between the source calls when they are all from a single instance of the location manager. You could certainly create multiple instances of the location manager and have each instance handle a different type of updates. The `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` call passes in the location manager instance as the first parameter, so you could easily use the source location manager in the call to distinguish different types of calls.